What does the fight involving Vishwakarma's bows in the Balakanda say about the Devas and the Trimurtis?
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana/d/doc365943.html

Thus addressed by Daśaratha, the powerful son of Jamadagni, disregarding his words, thus addressed Rāma,


These two foremost of bows, extraordinary, and worshipped of all the worlds, and stout, and powerful, surpassingly excellent, were constructed with care by Viśvakarman.


One of these, O foremost of men, for the destruction of Tripura, the celestials gave to Tryambaka, desirous of encounter, even that which, O Kākutstha, which you have snapped.


This second, which is irrepressible, was given to Viṣṇu, by the chiefs of the celestials. And, O Rāma, this bow belonging to Viṣṇu, capable of conquering hostile cities, is,


O Kākutstha, equal in energy to the bow belonging to Rudra. Once on a time the deities, with the object of ascertaining the respective prowess of Viṣṇu and the blue-throated one, asked the great-father, foremost of those abiding by truth, reading the intention of the deities, fomented a quarrel between them.


Upon that quarrel breaking out among the deities, there took place a mighty contest capable of making one’s hair stand on end, between Viṣṇu and the blue-throated one, each burning to beat the other down.


Then on Viṣṇu uttering a roar, Śiva’s bow of dreadful prowess became flaccid. And thereupon the three-eyed Mahaḍeva became moveless.


Upon the assembled gods with the saints and the Cāraṇas beseeching those two foremost of celestials, they became pacified.


Upon beholding that bow of Śiva rendered flaccid by Viṣṇu’s prowess, the deities with the saints acknowledged Viṣṇu as the more powerful.

Why do Brahma, Siva and Vishnu behave like schoolboys fighting after school at the behest of the Devas?  Clearly, this whole fight is behavior that doesn't behoove the Trimurtis.
Perhaps there is a deeper meaning to the story but present-day sectarians distort this story to make childish sectarian points.
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/tZycsKsA5y8
This representative of a sect formed in New York in the 1970s gives a highly distorted schoolboy-fight version of the story (in Hindi) and embellishes it by bringing in Narayaanstra that doesn't occur in the original.
